# Enlarging luks partition

Tags: partitioning, encryption, lvm, resize, luks

I'm getting new SSD disk soon and want to `dd` my old disk to new one. My disk is fully encrypted and using LVM. My new disk will be twice ad big as I have now. I was wondering how to use remaining space after clone. There should be around 120 GB free space on my disk.

I was thinking that maybe I could use `gparted` with live cd and enlarge my luks partition so it will use remaining space. But won't it break something since my disk is fully encrypted? If it will work should I do something else afterwards?

I read that I could also create new partition and add it to lvm group. But will data there be encrypted? Or should I encrypt second partition separately and somehow unlock it after providing password for my main luks partition?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions

Answer (score 0):

I don't think gparted can resize Luks partitions at the moment but it might change in the future. I think I saw some unmerged patches floating around.

Try KDE Partition Manager 3.0 if you are using Ubuntu 17.04. It supports resizing LUKS (as well as LVM partitions).

If you are on older Ubuntu, you can try some Live CD, e.g. Neon (https://neon.kde.org/download).

Install KDE Partition Manager using `sudo apt update; sudo apt install partitionmanager`